# How to print the numbers from 2 to the number that i use to check prime conditon

Tags: javascript, function

i have written code for checking if a number is prime or not. i want to print the prime numbers from 2 to the num lets say if my num =19 then the code most be printed prime numbers from 2 to 19.
how to use this function to achieve my output?

```
function checkprime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i <= num ** 1 / 2; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
checkprime(19);
```

Comment: use a for loop to push every found number into an `array`, then print array with or without a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, you want to printed prime numbers from 2 to 19 using the function that you write above. if the input is 19 the expected output will be 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 correct?

in order to do that you need to create another function to iterate the number and check whether it is prime or not. you can add this function to your code

```
function primeOutput(num) {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (checkprime(i) == true) {
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}

primeOutput(19);
```

the output will be

```
3
5
7
11
13
17
```